# Parsing through an object in a nest JSON object

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a json response object to get the hashID (objectiveHash) for each record, but I'm running into an error.

This is the error.

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Here is a snippit of the response.JSON for reference:

```
{
  "Response": {
    "records": {
      "data": {
        "featuredRecordHashes": [
          3241995275,
          3623956709,
          1257350901
        ],
        "records": {
          "18302305": {
            "state": 0,
            "objectives": [
              {
                "objectiveHash": 836033085,
                "progress": 1,
                "completionValue": 1,
                "complete": true,
                "visible": true
              }
            ],
            "intervalsRedeemedCount": 0
          },
          "100144154": {
            "state": 4,
            "objectives": [
              {
                "objectiveHash": 3797031509,
                "progress": 89,
                "completionValue": 100,
                "complete": false,
                "visible": true
              }
            ],
            "intervalsRedeemedCount": 0,
            "rewardVisibilty": [
              true,
              true
            ]
          }
...
```

This is the relevant code.

```
json_response = response.json()
        for record in json_response['Response']['records']['data']['records']:
            myRecord = record['objectives']
            for tst in myRecord:
                hashID = str(tst['objectiveHash'])
```

Based on some research, the issue seems to be that myRecords variable is being taken as a string as opposed to an object or list. So, when I try to parse it, I get the error because you can't parse a string. I'm not sure how to go about getting that value as a parseable object.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is getting the keys assigned to record variable.  records is a dictionary and iterating over a dictionary normally gets you the keys.

If you want the values then add .values() to the end of the json_response['Response']['records']['data']['records'] line.

If you want to have both the key and value then modify the code to have this:

```
for key, record in json_response['Response']['records']['data']['records'].items():
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

If you iter through a nested dict-object, you will get the keys, not the sub-dicts.

### Problem

For `record` applies, you want...

```
"18302305": {
    "state": 0,
    "objectives": [
      {
        "objectiveHash": 836033085,
        "progress": 1,
        "completionValue": 1,
        "complete": true,
        "visible": true
      }
    ],
    "intervalsRedeemedCount": 0
}
```

...but you get...

```
"18302305"
```

### Solution 1

Always refer to your data dict:

```
for record in json_response['Response']['records']['data']['records']:
    for tst in json_response['Response']['records']['data']['records'][record]['objectives']:
        hashID = str(tst['objectiveHash'])
        print(hashID)
```

### Solution 2

Copy the sub-dict (or rather create a pointer internally):

```
for record in json_response['Response']['records']['data']['records']:
    myRecord = json_response['Response']['records']['data']['records'][record]
    for tst in myRecord['objectives']:
        hashID = str(tst['objectiveHash'])
        print(hashID)
```

### Efficiency

Because they both refer to an address, they are equally efficient.

Proof:

```
for record in json_response['Response']['records']['data']['records']:
    myRecord = json_response['Response']['records']['data']['records'][record]
    print(myRecord is json_response['Response']['records']['data']['records'][record])
```